# EditText disappearing from dialog in Android

Tags: android, android-studio, user-interface, android-edittext

I need a couple of edittexts in my dialog, i added them normally in xml but they disappear when opened this is my code:

```
public class SubmissionDialog extends AppCompatDialogFragment {
    private TextProcessor tpCode;
    private EditText etOutput;
    private EditText etExpectedOutput;

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

        LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.view_submission_dialog, null);
        Bundle bundle = this.getArguments();

        builder.setView(view)
                .setTitle("Task submission.")
                .setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        // nothing
                    }
                });

        tpCode = (TextProcessor) view.findViewById(R.id.tpCodeDialog);
        etOutput = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.etDialogOutput);
        etExpectedOutput = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.etDialogExpectedOutput);

        tpCode.setTextContent(bundle.getString("code"));
        tpCode.setLanguage(new JavaLanguage());
        tpCode.setColorScheme(EditorTheme.INSTANCE.getMONOKAI());

        etOutput.setText(bundle.getString("output"));
        etExpectedOutput.setText(bundle.getString("expectedOutput"));

        return builder.create();
    }
}
```

It is esspecially wierd since I did it multiple times but only this time it disappears, i check bundle is not empty also in my xml there are no errors.

Comment: did you use constraint layout with height element of match constraint

Comment: @devfoFikiCar yes in edittext sections

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you told me in comments that you used contraint layout and had height elements of 0dp in comment above, you need to remove them since alert dialog does not have height constraint like usual layout, so your edittexts are there but because they match constraint that does not exist they are not visible. You should or use different layout type or wrap content, you really should not care about height in alert dialogs.

Comment: I changed to wrap content and it works. Thank you